# Bigquery Python client : how is it possible to know if my select query returns any data with a destination table in my configuration?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm encountering an issue while trying to determine whether a SELECT query in the BigQuery Python client returned any rows before inserting them into a destination table. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import time

client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
-- SELECT col1, col2 FROM project_id.dataset_id.source_table WHERE col2 is not null
"""

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination="project_id.dataset_id.destination_table")

query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
while query_job.state != "DONE":
    time.sleep(1)
    query_job.reload()

results = query_job.result()
total_rows_returned = results.total_rows

if total_rows_returned == 0:
    print("Query did not return any rows.")
else:
    print(f"Query returned {total_rows_returned} rows. Inserting into the destination table.")
```

The issue is that `total_rows_returned = results.total_rows` seems to return all rows from the destination table instead of the rows returned by the original SELECT query.

I've tried various approaches, including checking num_rows, num_dml_affected_rows, and total_rows from both query_job and results, but none of them provide the expected information.

Is there a reliable way to determine whether the SELECT query returned any rows before inserting them into the destination table in the BigQuery Python client?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the total_rows attribute of the query_job object itself. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import time

client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
-- SELECT col1, col2 FROM project_id.dataset_id.source_table WHERE col2 is not null
"""

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination="project_id.dataset_id.destination_table")

query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
while query_job.state != "DONE":
    time.sleep(1)
    query_job.reload()

# Check if the query returned any rows
if query_job.num_rows == 0:
    print("Query did not return any rows.")
else:
    print(f"Query returned {query_job.num_rows} rows. Inserting into the destination table.")
```

I replaced results.total_rows with query_job.num_rows. This should give you the number of rows returned by the original SELECT query before inserting them into the destination table.

Comment: well 'QueryJob' object has no attribute 'num_rows'

Comment: @fancyeffective try to use total_rows instead, but keep in mind that the value might be 'None', Let me know, if it works I will update the answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Despite exploring various methods, I have not found a straightforward and clean solution.

As a workaround, I use a solution that involves obtaining the total number of rows in the destination table both before and after executing the query. If the count before and after the query is the same, I infer that the SELECT query did not return any rows.

Here's a simplified version of the approach:

```
 try:
     table = client.get_table(destination_table)
     rows_before_operation = table.num_rows
     query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
     while query_job.state != "DONE":
         time.sleep(1)
         query_job.reload()
     #does other staff with the job_query

     table = client.get_table(destination_table)
     rows_after_operation = table.num_rows
     if rows_before_operation == rows_after_operation:
         raise QueryReturnsNone("custom message")
```